# Why does including brackets in a TikZ datavisualization label give me an error?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, errors, labels, brackets

My questions concerns the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
\tikz[scale=4]
    \datavisualization[
        school book axes,
        visualize as smooth line=myfunction,
        myfunction={pin in data={text=$f(x)$}}]
    data [set=myfunction, format=function] {
        var x : interval [0:1];
        func y = \value x^2;
    };
\end{document}
```

which makes the following pretty graph:
[image: Graph of y = x^2, with label]

The problem is that when I try to change my label text from `$f(x)$` to `$f[x]$` I receive the error `Missing $ inserted.` on the line containing `};`.

I figure it probably has to do with TikZ parsing the brackets before math-mode gets to them, but I don't know how to fix it. I tried replacing `[` and `]` with `\[` and `\]` but this didn't help at all. I also realized that I could replace `$f[x]$` with `$f$[$x$]`, but this seems like the wrong way to go.

How can I include brackets in my label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(La)TeX can not balance square brackets and it gets confused thinking that the  `]` in `f[x]` is closing the opening `[` from `\datavisualization`; help it by using an extra pair of braces,as in `{$f[x]$}` so the inner brackets are hidden:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\begin{document}
\tikz[scale=4]
    \datavisualization[
        school book axes,
        visualize as smooth line=myfunction,
        myfunction={pin in data={text={$f[x]$}}}]
    data [set=myfunction, format=function] {
        var x : interval [0:1];
        func y = \value x^2;
    };
\end{document}
```

[image]